# Class diagram regarding book exchange app

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Can *searchBook* be a title of class in class diagram?  Or do I need to put any noun? Is it compulsory that the names of classes should be nouns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML does not specifiy any naming conventions at all. You can choose the names you feel your audience will understand and/or is familiar with.

I think the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887799/naming-convention-for-uml) my help you too.

Comment: thank you..and can getByName() and getByUser() be the methods?