# Differences in Type and Naming Conventions for UML Class in Different Programming Languages

Tags: python, java, kotlin, uml

Are UML class representations different for each programming language, or do they adhere to a standard? I have conducted extensive research but remain confused.

For instance:

- In Python: set_name(): None
- In Java: setName(): void
- In Kotlin: setName(): Unit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not one "standard" for UML naming conventions. I would advise you use names similar to what you would use in the programming language you are using. As long as your intended reader understands the material then it is a good convention.

Most important is that whatever you choose remains consistent throughout your documentation.

See: [this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887799/naming-convention-for-uml).

Comment: Is it the same for types in programming languages as well?

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei Sure it is. Names are there to give things meaning that come to a common level between humans in oder to communicate.

Comment: @qwerty_so I meant data types, is the answer still yes? For example Unit in Kotlin, void in Java and None in Python.

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei You generally use the names of your target programming language. Otherwise you'll only add confusion or overhead when going between the UML diagram and your code.

Comment: @AliDehkhodaei Names are names. Be it operation, attribute, data type or whatever. So, yes, as well...

Comment: Please open a new question. This is for comments only.